# Need to rearrange HashMap key/value pairs

Tags: hashmap, hashset, key-value

I have set of key/value paired data in the form of a HashMap that that I am required to manipulate.

Here is the signature of the object I am looking at:

```
    Map<Consumer, ArrayList<EventMsg>> consumerMsgListMap = 
                                       new HashMap<Consumer, ArrayList<EventMsg>>();
```

The result of System.out.println(consumerMsgListMap.toString()) is the following:

> ConsumerA=[msg1, msg3], ConsumerB=[msg1, msg2, msg4], ConsumerC=[msg2, msg3]

As you can see each value() is a list rather than an individual value.

I need to figure out a way to rearrange the data such that for each *unique* EventMsg entry there is an associated Consumer. For example:

> msg1 needs to be associated with [ConsumerA, ConsumerB]
>
> msg2 needs to be associated with [ConsumerB, ConsumerC]
>
> msg3 needs to be associated with [ConsumerA, ConsumerC]
>
> msg4 needs to be associated with [ConsumerB]

This isn't a matter of simply reversing the K,V pairs.

I think the proper approach is to get uniqueness among all values by building up a separate HashSet but I can't figure out a way of getting at the values as Individual entities

> (e.g. msg1, msg3, msg1, msg2, msg4)

rather than as Groups of entities

> (e.g. [msg1, msg3], [msg1, msg2, msg4]).

This is probably obvious to the seasoned pro but at my stage of development I'm stumped. Hope I've stated the problem clearly. Thanks in advance if anyone has any ideas.

Here's the initial setup. Consumer could just as easily be String and EventMsg could just as easily be Integer:

```
  Map<Consumer, ArrayList<EventMsg>> consumerMsgListMap = new HashMap<Consumer, ArrayList<EventMsg>>();

  Consumer c1 = new Consumer("ConsumerA");
  Consumer c2 = new Consumer("ConsumerB");
  Consumer c3 = new Consumer("ConsumerC");

  ArrayList<EventMsg> msgListA = new ArrayList<EventMsg>();
  msgListA.add(new EventMsg("msg1"));
  msgListA.add(new EventMsg("msg3"));

  ArrayList<EventMsg> msgListB = new ArrayList<EventMsg>();
  msgListB.add(new EventMsg("msg1"));
  msgListB.add(new EventMsg("msg2"));
  msgListB.add(new EventMsg("msg4"));

  ArrayList<EventMsg> msgListC = new ArrayList<EventMsg>();
  msgListC.add(new EventMsg("msg2"));
  msgListC.add(new EventMsg("msg3"));

  consumerMsgListMap.put(c1, msgListA);
  consumerMsgListMap.put(c2, msgListB);
  consumerMsgListMap.put(c3, msgListC);
```

Comment: This is a java question?Which language are you using?

Comment: It looks like Java. You can't access the individual elements just using ArrayList.get() ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)

Answer (score 0):

It seems fairly straightforward to me. Pseudocode for adoubly-nested loop:

1. Allocate a new `Map<EventMsg, Set<Consumer>> result`
2. Iterate over `consumerMsgListMap.entries()`, which gives you `Map.Entry<Consumer, ArrayList<EventMsg>>` objects, one at a time.

   1. Set `key` = `entry.key()`, `value=entry.value()`
   2. For each `EventMsg e` in `value`,

      1. if `e` is not a key in `result`, then `result.put(e, new HashSet<Consumer>());`
      2. `result.get(e).add(key)`